# Page resizing and reshaping when scroll bar shows

Tags: css

I have a small problem with my website I'm building.

Everything is working fine, except that, if the contents on a page on the site is much, and the page is long, such that you have to scroll through the whole page with the browser's scroll bar to read all the contents on the page, the page resizes/repositions itself differently, and it won't position itself like other pages, whose content all occupy and don't need any scrolling.

I'm using HTML5 dtd, and using this CSS for the hole page:

```
<div id='container'>
<div id='wrapper'>
<!-- then the  whole content of the page is here-->
</div>
</div>
```

where

```
#container{     
  margin: 0px;  
  padding: 0px; 
}

#wrapper
{   
  text-align: left;     
  margin: 0px auto;     
  padding: 0px;     
  width: 900px; 
}
```

Please what could be wrong, I don't really know what I'm doing wrong, because the whole pages in the site positions itself differently from a page on the site with less content.

Here's the full code on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/iledev/1/.

Comment: did you try `body {overflow-y: scroll;}`

Answer (score 0):

Add a style to the element so that it will always show the scroll bars:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

This way the content won't reposition itself, since there will be no difference between smaller content and larger.

For mozilla firefox to play ball, you may need to add:

```
overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
```

Though that tip was from a year ago, so Firefox may have improved itself since then. Try it out.

Comment: `overflow-y` is supported since ff 1.5 and `-moz-scrollbars-vertical` is marked as deprecated.

Comment: Thanks guys, thanks a lot, it worked. But why is it behaving like that, is it normal for browsers to do that?

Comment: Yes, the default behavior of browsers is to expand the div to fit the size of the content. So they give us overflow-y (and overflow-x) in case we want to keep the div a constant size and, in this example, scroll the content inside the div.